# Unable to open 'osteram.tcc' and 'ios_base.h' when debugging in VS code

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm on Manjaro, and I have followed the VS code guide to install C++ on Linux and it have successfully build and ran a hello world app and other apps that I have build, but the problem I have discovered is that whenever I'm debugging and hit "Step into" `cout` or `cin` I get the following error message:

`Unable to open 'ios_base.h': Unable to read file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h').`

`Unable to open 'ostream.tcc': Unable to read file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc').`

and when I click on Create File, the following message shows up:
`Unable to write file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/build')`

`Unable to write file '/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/build')`

I have searched for the ios_base file and ostream file and found them in /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/, and I know I can run `cout` and `cin` operation with no problem it's just trying to step into them causes the error.

Here is also my Task.json file because I have saw some post talk about it.

````
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }```
````

Comment: It looks like you are trying to step into standard library functions. It is not possible unless you have standard library sources from which your standard library is built. This should not be a big problem since the implementation of the standard library is normally of no interest to application developers. If you have a specific need to debug the standard library, you can always download the source code of gcc itself (which includes libstdc++)  and build it yourself in debug mode.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. When I was using Visual Studio and hit F11 it won't shows me any error, I'm not trying to debug the std, I just want to move through me code line by line.

Comment: Visual Studio supports the "just my code" mode, gdb does not, it is a known gdb deficiency. Do not hit the "step into" key if you are on a line that is not calling your function. Hit "step over" instead. If you did step into for some reason, hit the "step out" key and continue. You can try to [skip the standard library files in gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html). This is not entirely satisfactory, because if standard library calls back your function, it too will be skipped. This is annoying but there seems to be no other solution ATM.